# How to create auto increment Column Based on the value

Tags: sql-server

IN SQL server i have table called Table  Employee . in  Employee talbe have one Column Field Name Dependennt Name Like Table .In this table Employee Dependent on  others. Dependvalue values Comes  repeat many Times  Dpendent Column.

```
Employee Name                         DependName  
Kelly, Sean                           Elieen Kelly 
Kelly, Sean                           Sienna Kelly 
Kelly, Sean                           Elieen Kelly 
Kelly, Sean                           Sienna Kelly
Kelly, Sean                           Kevin  Kelly
Kelly, Sean                           Mark  Kelly 
Neuenschwander                        Spide kelly 
Neuenschwander                        sumiln Kelly
```

In this Table  Employee Name  Repeat many time and also Dependent Employee  also repat many time. i have big File . i dont know How many dpendname is there SQL file.  its take  Long Sql file. So i want Table  Like this .spilit on based  on Employee name

```
 Employee Name        DependName1  DependName2    DependName3  DependName4
 Elieen Kelly         Elieen Kelly  Sienna Kelly  Kevin Kelly Mark Kelly 
Neuenschwander        Spide kelly   sumiln Kelly
```

Update :

```
  Employee Name        DependName1  DependName2    DependName3  DependName4
    Kelly, Sean       Elien Kelly   SieeaKelly    SieeaKelly    SieeaKelly
```

my table be like .in this SQL big file some more employee  it may be have more DependName . how to spilit Table Like. how to create column Basesd on DependName ? thanks in advance

Comment: billions of answers out there: how to split a string in sql

Comment: @Chanukya that's not a good duplicate. First, the OP is asking about *pivoting* not splitting. Second, there are many ways to split a string that weren't available in 2015. SQL Server 2016 even introduced the `STRING_SPLIT` function.

Comment: SQL doesn't deal with *files*, it deals with *tables*. That means that 1 or 1M rows, the statements are the same. It also means that you *have* to know how many columns you want in advance. You can't write a query that will return an arbitrary number of columns.  Your *client* though, may be able to do so. This transformation is called "pivoting".

Comment: Why did you just change the title to something completely irrelevant to the question?? What does auto incrementing have to do with converting rows to columns ????

Comment: Where did Alex come from?

Comment: sorry i now changed .  Kelly, Sean  Employeename  this employee have Two dependName but this Employee Fill value Automatically 3 and 4 Column sir its should   DependName wont repeat again  any  Row of Employee sir

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thank you so much Working Well., thank you sir again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple conditional aggregation in concert with Row_Number() (or Dense_Rank() to eliminate duplicates) would do the trick **if you don't need to go dynamic**

```
Declare @YourTable table (EmployeeName varchar(50), DependName  varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Kelly, Sean'   ,'Elieen Kelly'), 
('Kelly, Sean'   ,'Sienna Kelly'), 
('Kelly, Sean'   ,'Elieen Kelly'), 
('Kelly, Sean'   ,'Sienna Kelly'),
('Kelly, Sean'   ,'Kevin  Kelly'),
('Kelly, Sean'   ,'Mark  Kelly'), 
('Neuenschwander','Spide kelly'), 
('Neuenschwander','sumiln Kelly') 


Select EmployeeName
      ,DependName1  = max(case when RN=1 then DependName else '' end)
      ,DependName2  = max(case when RN=2 then DependName else '' end)
      ,DependName3  = max(case when RN=3 then DependName else '' end)
      ,DependName4  = max(case when RN=4 then DependName else '' end)
 From  (
            Select *,RN=Dense_Rank() over (Partition By EmployeeName Order by DependName)
             From  @YourTable
       ) A
 Group By EmployeeName
```

Returns

```
EmployeeName    DependName1     DependName2     DependName3   DependName4
Kelly, Sean     Elieen Kelly    Kevin  Kelly    Mark  Kelly   Sienna Kelly
Neuenschwander  Spide kelly     sumiln Kelly
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have 6 kids. Wouldn't work for the OP either if the rows weren't duplicate by accident (lazy copy pasting). You can't write a SQL query that returns an arbitrary number of columns. *Maybe* generating a CSV and splitting on the client would work. Better yet, pivot on the client

Comment: @john Cappelletti i will try sir your method sir

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Have 3 myself and about 20 of their friend who eat more than you can imagine.

Comment: For example, SSRS or another reporting tool could allow an arbitrary number of columns in a tablix report with some clever row/column grouping

Comment: @ john Cappelletti  Working . suppose one employee have two dependent remain fields its should be null.  but  remain fields  value fill preiovus one

Comment: @sripriya If you want null values just remove the   else ''     or you could have    else null.

Comment: thank you sir ..one more help sir.if suppose one Employee  have Two Same name Dependname but its should display one. how ti possible sir.

Comment: @sripriya Change Row_Number() to Dense_Rank()

Comment: working  fine sir . if suppose one  Empoloyee have only two dependName  other Employee four DependName  which Employee has Tep Dependname  Remain Two column Should be Null .but its 3 and 4 also come in value sir                                                                                                  Like this                                                                                                                       Alexander, Kathryn Grace E Alexander John M Alexander Lillian Mae Alexander Madeline Rose Alexander Madeline Rose Alexander Madeline Rose Alexander

Comment: @sripriya Not sure I understand your question

Comment: in my table i have so many Employee .suppose  one Employee have 2 dependname   and other Employee 4 dependname . which employee employee Two dependname    this  employee 3 ,4 Column Should be null.but  i getting value 3 and 4 Column which  Employee  have Two DependName this 3 and 4 value come repeat sir

Comment: @sripriya Do these two employees have the same name?

Comment: Employee name Different but Dependname Name repeat many time same employee sir . also i update my Question i posted what getting  sir